# C# Single vs List of Objects for a class

Tags: c#

I have a class that inherits from an interface and implements a method that saves a single object and another method that saves a list of objects of type lets say 'iX':-

```
public class XX : iX
{

  public override string A;
  public override string B;

  internal Some_Method(iX item)
    {
       A = item.A; B - item.B;
    }

   private void Single_Save(specific_type x)
    {
      //// some code here ///
    }

   private void Multiple_Save(List<specific_type> x)
    {
      /// some code here ///
    } 

   internal void Save()
    {
      var y = AnotherFunction(this);
      Save(y);
    }

   internal void SaveAll()
    {
      Multiple_Save(that_list);   <----------- how do I get that list ??
    }
}
```

Now from my Business class I would like to do something like this:-

```
public static void SaveObj(iX item)  
 { 
    var singleobj = new XX(item);
    singleobj.Save();
 }
```

The single save works. But I am having issues writing code that will allow me to save a list of objects as such:-

```
public static void SaveObjects(List<iX> items)
 {
    var multipleobj = new XX(items);   <------- this will not work, because my class is expecting a single object of type iX....
    multipleobj.SaveAll();
 }
```

** The caveat to this is that, both Multiple_Save and Single_Save methods use different forms of saving info and need to be used separately by respective methods aka cannot foreach through a list of items and Single_Save one at a time.

Can someone point me to the concept I should be looking at to figure this scenario out?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] including the constructors for `iX` and `XX`. _The short answer is you need to add a new constructor to `XX` that takes the list you want. Or change `SaveAll` to have a parameter of the list instead._

Answer (score 0):

It would be far simpler if you had a separate a collection class. Let an `XX` represent a single item, and put them together in a collection if you want to work with them as a unit. It's easy to create a collection class (just inherit from `List<T>` and all its methods and its enumerator become available from `this`). For example:

```
class XXList : List<XX>
{
    public void SaveAll()
    {
        foreach (var xx in this) xx.Save();
    }
}
```

So you can use it like this:

```
var list = new XXList
{
    new XX(item1),
    new XX(item2),
    new XX(item3)
};
list.SaveAll();
```

Comment: And, don't forget, you can create a list with a single object in it.

Answer (score 0):

You need multiple constructors in your class. Provided they have different parameters, method overloading allows you to create multiple methods with the same name.

Example:

```
public class XX : IX
{
    public IX SingleItem { get; set; }
    public List<IX> ListOfItems { get; set; }
    public XX(IX item)
    {
        SingleItem = item;
    }
    public XX(List<IX> items)
    {
        ListOfItems = items;
    }
}
```

You could even then combine your save methods into one if you wanted too:

```
public void Save()
{
    if (ListOfItems != null)
    {
        //code to save multiple
    }
    else if (Item != null)
    {
        //code to save one
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what are you trying to do. I can not see the construction of XX class but create a overload constructor

```
public XX(List<yourClass> item)
{

}
```

This will have your object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like below:

```
// Create the list
List<ClassName> List = new List<Ix>();

// Create instance of your class
Ix ix = new Ix();

// Add the new object to the list
classList.Add(ix);
```

You can also use Types.

In your

```
private void Multiple_Save(List<specific_type> x)
{
  If (x != null)
  {
    foreach (var ix in x) 
        SingleSave(ix);
  /// some code here ///
  }
}
```

I believe this requires System.Collections.Generic as namespace.